# Проблемы записи объекта в файл и чтения из него

Tags: c++, файлы, классы

Пытаюсь записать и считать из файла класс. Написал все работает. Решил раскинуть по функциям, но функция считывания из файла почему-то выбивает исключение "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
_Pnext было 0x1190F04.". Думаю проблема в том, что я как-то неправильно возвращаю экземпляр класса из функции. Хотя я не знаю как можно сделать лучше.

Класс Человек

```
class Man
{
public:
    string name;
    int num;
    Man() {}
    Man(string n,int n1)
    {
        this->name = n;
        this->num = n1;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        cout << "Член семьи: " << name <<" : "<<num<< endl;
    }
};
```

Класс "Семья", содержащий в себе экземпляр класса "Человек"

```
class Family
{
public:
    string name;
    Man man;
    Family(){}
    Family(string n, Man m)
    {
        this->name = n;
        this->man = m;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        cout << "Семья: " << name << endl;
        man.Print();
    }
};
```

Функции для записи и считывания из файла

```
void WriteInFile(Family f)
{
    ofstream file("file.txt", ofstream::binary | ofstream::app);
    if (!file.is_open())
        cout << "Файл не открыт";
    else
    {
        file.write((char*)&f, sizeof(Family));
        file.close();
    }
}
Family ReadInFile()
{
    Family myObject;

    ifstream file("file.txt");
    file.seekg(0);
    file.read((char*)&myObject, sizeof(Family));
    file.close();
    return myObject;
}
```

Код программы (код в комментариях работает)

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");

    Man man("Отец",12345);
    Family family("Петровченко", man);

    WriteInFile(family);

    Family test;
    test = ReadInFile();
    test.Print();
    /*
    ofstream file("file.txt", ofstream::binary | ofstream::app);
    file.write((char*)&family, sizeof(Family));
    file.close();

    Family family2;
    ifstream file1("file.txt");
    file1.seekg(0);
    file1.read((char*)&family2, sizeof(Family));
    file1.close();
    family2.Print();*/
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что вы записываете через `file.write((char*)&f, sizeof(Family));` и читаете `file.read((char*)&myObject, sizeof(Family));` не тривиально копируемые объекты [TriviallyCopyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable), [std::is_trivially_copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable).

У вас в классе есть поле `string name`, в `string` хранится указатель на область памяти. Сохраняя через `file.write` вы сохраняете именно этот указатель (адрес участка памяти), а не само значение (имя).